# How to use ESM and TypeScript in Node.js with test coverage

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I'm trying to use ESM and TypeScript in Node.js v14. This is not hard and exist some questions for it:

- [How to use ts-node ESM with node modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600063/how-to-use-ts-node-esm-with-node-modules)
- [Can't run my Node.js Typescript project TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /app/src/App.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension)

Try to summarize it in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2022",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

> If not provide `esm: true`, you can use `ts-node-esm` instead of `ts-node`
>
> For example: `npx ts-node-esm my-code.ts`

But main problem is that when using [nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc), it can't correctly collect the statements/branches that have passed.

I have tried [nyc-config-typescript](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/tree/master/packages/nyc-config-typescript) and [esm-loader-hook](https://github.com/istanbuljs/esm-loader-hook) but none of these works.

How can I handle this problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to tackle this problem two days and finally "fix" it by using [c8](https://github.com/bcoe/c8)

You can see the example by [example repo](https://github.com/evan361425/playground-ts-esm). In the example, I'm using [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io) but you can use other testing framework (e.g. [mocha](https://mochajs.org))
as you want.

Finally you can execute testing with coverage by:

```bash
npx c8 ts-node jasmine.ts
```

Comment: Works like a charm! In my case, I had to add the test files in the jasmine.ts file like this: *await jasmine.execute(["tests/*[sS]pec.?(m)ts"]);*
Otherwise the test files were not found. Thanks for providing the tutorial!