# ts-node never work when type: module is in package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

This is my project:

```
.
├── package.json
└── test.ts
```

This is my package.json file (only):

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

And this is my test.ts file (only):

```
console.log("hello world")
```

When I run

```
$ npx ts-node ./test.ts
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /home/$am/Documents/projects/temp/test.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:124:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:84:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:603:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26)
    at ESMLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:480:17)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:34) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

Is there any solution to this?

- I am running nodejs v18.17.1.
- I **don't** have typescript or ts-node globally installed.

Comment: There are a few different options you might try, depending on your exact use-case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600063/how-to-use-ts-node-esm-with-node-modules talks about them in some detail

Comment: Does this answer your question？ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension

Comment: @LinDu. Not sure,