# VSCode Shows Errors for ES6 Imports In Deno

Tags: visual-studio-code, deno

A few days ago, I was getting started with [Deno](https://deno.land), a *secure runtime for JS and TS*. I use VSCode as my Deno IDE. Deno works just as intended, so I don't think it is an issue with the executable.

However, when I came to module imports (from local files), I had a problem. Deno requires the extension of the file to be specified in imports *(Deno uses ES6 imports)*, but normal TypeScript doesn't, so when I don't specify the extension VSCode is fine, but running with Deno raises an error. Specifying the extension gives me error squiggles in VSCode but Deno works fine.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56201361/14925444) answer, and the `@ts-ignore` comment indeed works, but I think there should be a better solution to this.

So, is there another extension / configuration option / any other way to remove the squiggles **without** `@ts-ignore`? *(Because it kinda becomes a problem if you want to import from a large batch of files)*